# How to split the array value in python?

Tags: python

I have an array `S = [1, 10, 14, 25, 62, 85, 20, 95]`. I need to devide `S` to two sector using numpy.

Expected output is:

```
S1 = [1, 10, 14, 25]
S2 = [62, 85, 20, 95]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the array easily:

```
import numpy as np
S = np.array([1, 3, 5, 10, 2, 4, 9, 5, -1])
S1 = np.array_split(S, 2)
print(S1)
```

also without external library

```
S = [1, 3, 5, 10, 2, 4, 9, 5, -1]
S1 = S[:4]
S2 = S[4:9]
print(S1)
print(S2)
```

Comment: Why import an external (and HEAVY) library just to split a list in two when you can achieve the same thing with ranges?

Comment: I think it's not good to hard code ranges. What if elements are added to array.

Comment: @accdias He is mention with the help of `numpy` , that's why i'm preferring

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the array into two halves, you can do it in this way:

```
S = [1, 10, 14, 25, 62, 85, 20, 95]
S1 = S[:len(S)//2]
S2 = S[len(S)//2:]
```